# dartUri: Unresolved uri: dart:web_sql , dartUri: Unresolved uri: dart:ui

Tags: flutter, api, asp.net-web-api, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

When I integrate my Asp.Net web API in Flutter it will display the following errors after run on Chrome Debugger..

```
dartUri: Unresolved uri: dart:web_sql
dartUri: Unresolved uri: dart:ui
```

**NOTE:**
I run this code in VS CODE.
when i run this code in its default windows debugger it doesn't show any error.
Also it display data from database.
But it cannot insert data in database.
When same code i run in Chrome debugger it will display the errors mentioned above.

**main.dart Code:**

```
import 'package:api_call/API%20-%201/ui/BooksUI.dart';
import 'package:api_call/API-Sr-Umar/Api_Config.dart';
import 'package:api_call/ApiCall.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() async {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: ApiConfig(),
    );
  }
}
```

**ApiConfig.dart Code**

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class ApiConfig extends StatefulWidget {
  const ApiConfig({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ApiConfig> createState() => _ApiConfigState();
}

class _ApiConfigState extends State<ApiConfig> {
  List<Books> bdata = [];
  Future<void> AddBook() async {
    print('Add Book Called');
    var response = await http.post(Uri.parse("http://192.168.56.1/MyFirstApi/api/TestApi/AddBook"),
        headers: <String, String>{'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'},
        body: jsonEncode(<String, dynamic>{
          "ID": 1,
          "BNAME": "BIO",
          "BPRICE": 180,
          "BPUBYEAR": "2001",
        }));

    print(response.body);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print('Inserted');
    } else {
      print('Insertion Failed');
    }
  }

  Future<void> getAllBooks() async {
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse('http://192.168.56.1/MyFirstApi/api/TestApi/getAllBooks'));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print('Successfully Called');
      print(response.body);
      print('Decoding');
      Iterable listt = jsonDecode(response.body);
      bdata = listt.map((e) => Books.fromMap(e)).toList();
      setState(() {
// bdata;
      });
    } else {
      print('Fetching Failed');
    }
  }

  TextEditingController id = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController bname = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController bprice = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController bpubyear = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Api Config'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          myTextField(id, 'Enter Id'),
          myTextField(bname, 'Enter Name'),
          myTextField(bprice, 'Enter Price'),
          myTextField(bpubyear, 'Enter Publish Year'),
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                AddBook();
              },
              child: Text("Add Book")),
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                getAllBooks();
              },
              child: Text("Get All Books")),
          ListView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            itemCount: bdata.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Text(bdata[index].id.toString() +
                  " " +
                  bdata[index].bname.toString() +
                  " " +
                  bdata[index].bprice.toString() +
                  " " +
                  bdata[index].bpubyear.toString());
            },
            shrinkWrap: true,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

TextField myTextField(TextEditingController ctrl, String htext) {
  return TextField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: htext),
    controller: ctrl,
  );
}

class BooksRecord {
  late int id;
  late String bname;
  late int bprice;
  late int bpubyear;
  BooksRecord(this.id, this.bname, this.bprice, this.bpubyear);
  BooksRecord.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> mp) {
    id = mp['ID'];
    bname = mp['BNAME'];
    bprice = mp['BPRICE'];
    bpubyear = mp['BPUBYEAR'];
  }
}

class Books {
  late int id;
  late String bname;
  late int bprice;
  late int bpubyear;
  Books(this.id, this.bname, this.bprice, this.bpubyear);

  int getID() => id;
  String getBName() => bname;
  int getBPrice() => bprice;
  int getBPubYear() => bpubyear;

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    Map<String, dynamic> mp = Map<String, dynamic>();
    mp['ID'] = id;
    mp['BNAME'] = bname;
    mp['BPRICE'] = bprice;
    mp['BPUBYEAR'] = bpubyear;
    return mp;
  }

  Books.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    id = map['ID'];
    bname = map['BNAME'];
    bprice = map['BPRICE'];
    bpubyear = map['BPUBYEAR'];
  }
}
```

Help Me to Solve This Error

Pics of Run in Default Windows Debugger:
[image]

click on add book error in WINDOWS debugger:

```
flutter: Add Book Called
flutter: "An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details."
flutter: Insertion Failed
```

When same code run in chrome debugger:

```
dartUri: Unresolved uri: dart:web_sql
dartUri: Unresolved uri: dart:ui
```

Comment: What version of flutter are you using ?

Comment: Seems to be a bug with Flutter itself. You can follow the progress [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/101639)

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue in [dart-lang/webdev](https://github.com/dart-lang/webdev/issues/1579) that affected Flutter. The [issue was fixed](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/101639#issuecomment-1103203606) once the update on Dart webdev was rolled-out to Flutter as well.